# Difference between 'to cause to become' and 'to cause'

Tags: complementation, causatives, linking-verbs

> [[Random House Dictionary]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/make?s=t), s.v. ***make***
>   3. **to cause to be or become; render**: to make someone happy.
>   8. **to cause, induce, or compel**: to make a horse jump a barrier.

What’s the difference between 3 and 8 in their meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both uses of *make* have the sense of causing something to be predicated of the Direct Object. There are a couple ways of parsing this, and it doesn't really matter how you represent it

> [Subj] *MAKE* [<sub>non-finite clause</sub> [Subj2] [Pred] ] ... *OR*
>   [Subj] *MAKE* [<sub>arg1</sub> [DirObj] ] [<sub>arg2</sub> [Pred] ]

The difference between 3 and 8 is that in 3 the verb in [Pred] is omitted, because it is a copula (*BE*, *BECOME* or the like) and its 'sense' is already evident in *MAKE*, while in 8 the verb must be included because it is an action performed by [Subj2].

> 1. I made the horse happy = I made the horse [become] happy.
> 2. I made the horse jump the fence.

There are other constructions besides *MAKE* which have the same sense but call for different arguments. Where *MAKE* takes the unmarked infinitive in [Pred], *CAUSE* takes the **marked** infinitive and does not omit a copular verb in [Pred]. More elaborately, *BRING IT ABOUT* requires a finite *that* clause.

> I caused the horse **to become** happy.
>   I caused the horse **to jump** the fence.
>   I brought it about **that** the horse **became** happy.
>   I brought it about **that** the horse **jumped** the fence.

Comment: Why! your essence can’t be found anywhere. I’ve written down what you say on my grammar book; and your name. For when time elapsed, the note itself has no clear authority if there isn’t reliable source: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The basic difference is that the verb *cause* in English cannot be followed by an *adjective*, only a *verb* or a *noun*.

The following mean the same thing:

> I made him happy,
>   I caused him to become happy,

while

> *I caused him happy,

is wrong. So if *make* is followed by an adjective, the definition must be *to cause to become* or *to cause to be*.

On the other hand, you can say both

> I made the horse jump the fence,
>   I caused the horse to jump the fence,

so if *make* is followed by a verb, *to cause to* is a good definition.

Answer (score 2):

The major **semantic** difference is that meaning #3:

> to cause to be or become; render: **to make someone happy**.

means that you or another living being or Mother Nature has done something that induces a feeling a joy, pleasure, or happiness in someone. The someone who is happy because you, e.g., smiled at him, his dog was excited to see him, or it snowed and school was called off for the day. When I was in the Navy, our base commander tried to "make us" feel a positive emotion when he told us that everyone would attend the Christmas party, and "you will all have fun!" Impossible! He could make us all attend the party by threatening to punish us if we didn't show up, but he certainly could **not** make us have fun and enjoy ourselves.

Meaning #8, however:

> to cause, induce, or compel: **to make a horse jump a barrier**.

means that you or another living being or Mother Nature has done something that forces someone else to do something, probably against her will, e.g., you've pointed a gun at her and demanded that she give you all the money in the cash register, a bee sting made her wince in pain, or an earthquake made her flee for her life. Horses don't go jumping fences for the hell of it. They jump on command (meaning #8) or when they want to escape a corral.